# Postgresql failed to start server (startserver.vbs) on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (64b)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, postgresql

Trying to install postgresql in a Windows Server R2 Entreprise (64b) I get this:

```
Iniciando el servidor de bases de datos...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\installer\server\startserver.vbs" postgresql-x64-9.3
Script exit code: 1

Script output:
 Starting postgresql-x64-9.3
Failed to start the database server (7)

Script stderr:
 Program ended with an error exit code
```

I tried every solution I found (all of stackoverflow I found and more) but I'm still getting this error.

Link to the complete log: http://pastebin.com/7t6dMEH0

Thanks for all.

Comment: Have you read the wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#Common_installation_errors ?

Comment: Yes, I checked everything in the wiki, but still stuck with this problem.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software on the machine, or a software firewall other than Windows Firewall?

Comment: The only thing the machine had was a Malwarebytes Anti-Malware software, but I removed it. This was one of the first steps I did once I saw the wiki.

Comment: Hm. I've never seen that particular exit code before. Can you pastebin `"C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\installer\server\startserver.vbs` too please and link to it here?

Comment: Yes, here it is http://pastebin.com/wj21F5vc.

Comment: If the return code 7 is from `pg_ctl` then, looking at the source code, it'd be the return value of GetLastError after invoking CreateRestrictedProcess. 7 is `ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED (The storage control blocks were destroyed)`. Which makes little sense unless you have serious file system corruption, broken DLLs, buggy hook DLLs, etc. Unfortunately searches for the error code are so full of search-spammer crud and scams that it's hard to find any real info.

Comment: Could it be that the msvbvm60.dll the installation was asking for is broken? I get it and registered it manually.

Comment: @cacafuti Er ... yes. That'd be it. You should really mention things like that in advance. **NEVER** just go downloading random DLLs. Among other things, they're often modified to carry malware. They can also be for the wrong architecture/version, or broken in all sorts of other ways.

Comment: unless ... are you running Windows Server 2008 Core (i.e. the one with no graphical interface, just a terminal)?

Comment: No, it have graphical interface. I'm going to see now the dlls issue but seems more to be my boss work (I can't freely restore a machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, the poster found a copy of `msvbvm60.dll` (a component of the Microsoft Visual Basic 6 runtime that should be a core part of the operating system) somewhere on the Internet when they had issues with the installer asking for it.

This sounds like a badly broken system that might be a candidate for a reinstall, or System Restore to an old state. While I doubt the `msvbvm60.dll` issue is the direct culprit, it suggests that this is likely a badly compromised system, as you should never be missing `msvbvm60.dll`. Whether it's file system corruption, malware, or user action, this might be a good time to reinstall a clean system.

Comment: dll's broken. System Restore needed to solve this problem. Thanks for your help.